# Add multiple values using $addToSet Mongo operator

Tags: arrays, mongodb

[`$addToSet` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) *adds a value to an array only if the value is not already in the array. If the value is in the array, `$addToSet` does not modify the array.*

I want to insert two values that should not be duplicated via one request. Is this possible?

I tried to pass an array to `$addToSet` operator but it inserted an array instead of each value from that array.

```
$ mongo test
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> db.c.insert({a: [1, 2, 3]})
> db.c.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53511a255a82cd559393d840"), "a" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
> db.c.update({}, {$addToSet: {a: [2, 4]}})
> db.c.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53511a255a82cd559393d840"), "a" : [ 1, 2, 3, [ 2, 4 ] ] }
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

From [the docs for `$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet):

> If the value is an array, `$addToSet` appends the whole array as a
>   single element. To add each element of the value separately, use
>   `$addToSet` with the `$each` modifier. See Modifiers for details.

So you should use this instead:

```js
db.c.update({}, {$addToSet: {a: {$each: [2, 4]}}})
```

Answer (score 7):

Yep. But you need the **`$each`** modifier to be added in your statement:

```
db.c.update({},{ $addToSet: { a: {$each: [ 2, 4 ] } } })
```

And the result:

```
{ "a" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
```