# MongoDB add n elements to an array field only if not exists

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Given:

```
db.alphabet.find()
[
  { _id: 1, letters: [ 'a', 'b' ] },
  { _id: 2, letters: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] },
  { _id: 3, letters: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f' ] }
]
```

Is there a way to add 'c', 'f' into `letters` to all documents without duplicate elements?
This would be the result:

```
db.alphabet.find()
[
  { _id: 1, letters: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f' ] },
  { _id: 2, letters: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f' ] },
  { _id: 3, letters: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f' ] }
]
```

I tried:

```
db.alphabet.updateMany({}, { $addToSet: { letters: "c"}, $addToSet: { letters: "f"}})
```

However it doesn't work because seems like you can only use one `$addToSet` (the last one wins).

Comment: You tried to use some options in the `updateMany` function? like this  `{ new:true, runValidators: true, upsert: true }` ?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154217/add-multiple-values-using-addtoset-mongo-operator)?